# Estoy trabajando con una tabla llamada person, y cuando ejecuto el programa me arroja el error 500

Tags: php, laravel

este es el código de mi controller donde hago el llamado, pero me sigue arrojando el error, soy nuevo en larave, por lo tanto lo que quiero hacer en un CRUD, había realizado uno anteriormente, y no me dio este problema pero con esta tabla llamada person me presenta el error, utilice los métodos para obviar la convención pero nada, sigue presentado el error

```php
<?php
        
        namespace

 App\Http\Controllers\admin;
    
    use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
    use App\Models\Person;
    use Illuminate\Http\Request;
    
    class PersonController extends Controller
    {
        /**
         * Display a listing of the resource.
         *
         * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
         */
        public function index()
        {
            $donors = Person::all();
            return view('admin.persons.index');
        }
    
        /**
         * Show the form for creating a new resource.
         *
         * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
         */
        public function create()
        {
            return view('admin.persons.create');
        }
```

este es el código del model, donde obvio la convencion

```php
    <?php
    
    namespace App\Models;
    
    use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
    use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
    
    class Person extends Model
    {
        use HasFactory;
        protected $table = 'person';
        protected $primary_key = 'id_person';
    }
```

esta es mi rutas

```
    use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
    use App\Http\Controllers\Admin\HomeController;
    use App\Http\Controllers\Admin\RequestoringController;
    use App\Http\Controllers\admin\PersonController;
    
    Route::get('', [HomeController::class, 'index'])->name('admin.home');
    
    Route::resource('requestorings', RequestoringController::class)->names('admin.requestorings');
    
    Route::resource('persons', PersonController::class)->names('admin.persons');
```

Comment: Error status 500 es un mensaje genérico. Revisa los logs de laravel y actualiza la pregunta con información más precisa.

Comment: App\Http\Controllers\admin;

    use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
    use App\Models\Person;
    use Illuminate\Http\Request;

    class PersonController extends Controller
    {
        /**
         * Display a listing of the resource.
         *
         * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
         */
        public function index()
        {
            $donors = Person::all();
            return view('admin.persons.index');
        }

Comment: Eso que has copiado es el código de tu controlador. No hay mensaje de error allí. De todos modos, de entrada, si estás intentando mostrar el listado de personas en el ```index```, empieza por pasar el ```$donors``` como parámetro a la vista, o sino no habrá nada qué listar. De hecho, no me extrañaría que el error 500 fuese precisamente Blade tratando de leer una variable ```$donors``` no definida.