# Error 500 en la ejecuccion

Tags: laravel

Estos son los Long que me arroja

```
    [previous exception] [object] (PDOException(code: 42S02): SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'bloodbank.people' doesn't exist at C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\bloodbank\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Database\\Connection.php:368)
[stacktrace]
#0 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\bloodbank\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Database\\Connection.php(368): PDO->prepare('select * from `...')
#1 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\bloodbank\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Database\\Connection.php(705): Illuminate\\Database\\Connection->Illuminate\\Database\\{closure}('select * from `...', Array)
#2 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\bloodbank\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Database\\Connection.php(672): Illuminate\\Database\\Connection->runQueryCallback('select * from `...', Array, Object(Closure))
#3 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\bloodbank\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Database\\Connection.php(376): Illuminate\\Database\\Connection->run('select * from `...', Array, Object(Closure))
#4 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\bloodbank\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Database\\Query\\Builder.php(2385): Illuminate\\Database\\Connection->select('select * from `...', Array, true)
#5 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\bloodbank\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Database\\Query\\Builder.php(2373): Illuminate\\Database\\Query\\Builder->runSelect()
#6 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\bloodbank\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Database\\Query\\Builder.php(2907): Illuminate\\Database\\Query\\Builder->Illuminate\\Database\\Query\\{closure}()
#7 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\bloodbank\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Database\\Query\\Builder.php(2374): Illuminate\\Database\\Query\\Builder->onceWithColumns(Array, Object(Closure))
#8 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\bloodbank\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Database\\Eloquent\\Builder.php(625): Illuminate\\Database\\Query\\Builder->get(Array)
#9 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\bloodbank\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Database\\Eloquent\\Builder.php(609): Illuminate\\Database\\Eloquent\\Builder->getModels(Array)
#10 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\bloodbank\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Database\\Eloquent\\Model.php(568): Illuminate\\Database\\Eloquent\\Builder->get(Array)
#11 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\bloodbank\\app\\Http\\Controllers\\Admin\\PersonController.php(18): Illuminate\\Database\\Eloquent\\Model::all()
#12 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\bloodbank\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Controller.php(54): App\\Http\\Controllers\\admin\\PersonController->index()
#13 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\bloodbank\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\ControllerDispatcher.php(45): Illuminate\\Routing\\Controller->callAction('index', Array)
#14 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\bloodbank\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Route.php(262): Illuminate\\Routing\\ControllerDispatcher->dispatch(Object(Illuminate\\Routing\\Route), Object(App\\Http\\Controllers\\admin\\PersonController), 'index')
#15 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\bloodbank\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Route.php(205): Illuminate\\Routing\\Route->runController()
#16 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\bloodbank\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Router.php(721): Illuminate\\Routing\\Route->run()
```

Comment: Estaría bien saber que estás haciendo, cual es el código que estás usando, qué es lo que pretendes hacer...

Comment: Supongo que lo que quisiste hacer es ampliar la info de [esta pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/514876/estoy-trabajando-con-una-tabla-llamada-person-y-cuando-ejecuto-el-programa-me-a). Si es así, deberías [editar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/514876/edit) aquella en lugar de abrir otra.

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Answer (score 0):

Podría ser debido a la falta de una tabla en la base de datos.

Mi recomendación es que revises la base de datos **bloodbank** y te asegures de que existe la tabla **people**. También puedes revisar las migraciones de la aplicación para ver si existe allí, encontrarás las migraciones en la carpeta **database/migrations**.

Si este es un proyecto en desarrollo, puedes volver a correr las migraciones con el comando **php artisan migrate:fresh** siempre que no tengas información importante en la base de datos. Con esto recuperarás la estructura de base de datos del proyecto.